# JPA InheritanceType.JOINED how to write relationship entities of parent class

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, inheritance

I have a parent entity class (**Instrument**) with three children (**Stock, Bond, Etf**).  The parent class has also a OneToMany relationship with class (**InstrumentPrice**).  The JPA joined strategy is used between parent entity and children entities.
When a child is persisted (ex. Stock), then an entry in Instrument is automatically persisted as well with all the common properties. 
That works fine. 
But, how do you create an entry for the class **InstrumentPrice** ?
Do I have to read the entity Instrument from the DB after having persisted a Stock, and update Instrument with InstrumentPrice ?

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    protected int id;

}
```

Parent Class **Instrument**

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "instr_type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING, length = 1)
@Table(name = "instrument")

public class Instrument extends BaseEntity {

    @Column
    private String symbol;

    @Column
    private String isin;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column
    private boolean active;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "instrument", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<InstrumentPrice> instrumentPriceList;

    // public getters & setters
    ....
```

class **InstrumentPrice**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "instrumentprice")
public class InstrumentPrice extends BaseEntity {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "instrument_id", nullable = false)
    private Instrument instrument;

    @Column
    private LocalDate date;
    @Column
    private double open;
    @Column
    private double high;
    @Column
    private double low;
    @Column
    private double close;
    @Column
    private long volume;

    // public getters & setters
    ....
```

Child Class **Stock**

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("S")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "id")
@Table(name = "stock")
public class Stock extends Instrument { 

...  fields specific to Stock ...

}
```

Comment: You can create an `InstrumentPrice` instance and set the `Instrument` or `Stock` with `setInstrument`. After perstisting the `InstrumetPrice` you can load the `Instrument` or `Stock` and you will find your InstrumentPrice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set both sides of relation. In Instrument class create method for adding instrumentPrice entity.

```
public void addInstrumentPrice(ip){
   instrumentPriceList.add(ip);
   ip.setInstrument(this);
}
```

Comment: How and when do I have to call these methods  ?  When I persist a Stock, I don't  have an instance of Instrument yet.  Plus, how to I obtain an instance of Instrument ?

Comment: Before persist. Stock is subclass of Istrument i.e. it inherits this method. You can call it on Stock and other subclasses.

Comment: It solved my issue.  I didn't realize that Stock extends from Instrument, and thus I can set Stock as Foreign Key  on InstrumentPrice